# Does Aloe Vera cure diseases?

Tags: cancer, disease, herbalism

Many sites claim that Aloe Vera can cure diseases and sicknesses such as Arthritis and prevent diseases such as cancer. Is there any scientific merit at all to all those claims?

**Example sites:**

[Natural News](http://www.naturalnews.com/021858_aloe_vera_gel.html)

[How Stuff Works](http://health.howstuffworks.com/wellness/natural-medicine/herbal-remedies/aloe-vera-herbal-remedies.htm)

A simple [Google search](https://www.google.co.il/#q=aloe+vera+cure) reveals hundreds of sites like that.

Comment: I added references, I think the question should be reopened.

Comment: "Unclear what you're asking"? I don't see how can it get any clearer than "Does Aloe Vera cure diseases?"

Comment: The claim should be more specific... *which* disease? It may be that Aloe Vera can cure hiccups, but can't cure cancer. So the claim should be made more specific.

Answer (score 2):

From The National Center for Complementary and Alternative Medicine: http://nccam.nih.gov/health/aloevera

> What the Science Says:
>   Aloe latex contains strong laxative compounds.
>   Products made with various components of aloe (aloin, aloe-emodin, and
>   barbaloin) were at one time regulated by the FDA as oral
>   over-the-counter (OTC) laxatives. In 2002, the FDA required that all
>   OTC aloe laxative products be removed from the U.S. market or
>   reformulated because the companies that manufactured them did not
>   provide the necessary safety data. Early studies show that topical
>   aloe gel may help heal burns and abrasions. One study, however, showed
>   that aloe gel inhibits healing of deep surgical wounds. Aloe gel has
>   not been shown to prevent burns from radiation therapy. There is not
>   enough scientific evidence to support aloe vera for any of its other
>   uses.

Comment: +1, although some primary evidence (i.e. peer-reviewed studies, which should be easy enough to find) would be a nice addition.

Comment: I found an interesting study on aloe toxicology, but it's behind a pay-wall.

Comment: If CAM people themselves admit that there is no evidence for it, that seems pretty conclusive to me ;-_

Comment: @hdhondt: oh, sure, I am not contesting that. It's just that having a primary source in addition to that would make the answer even better, that's all!